# how to make first letter capital in of string in angular js

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am trying to make a filter which show first letter capital of string .I am able to solve the problem but when I have one Question on that .I need to understand the regex .Mean what regax is doing here .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JddwwV

Could you please tell me what is the meaning of regex `replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*)`

what is use of this expression.

```
angular.module('CustomFilter', []).
  filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input, all) {
      console.log(input)
      return (!!input) ? input.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function(txt){
        console.log(txt+":txt")
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}) : '';
    }
  });

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'hello, world.';
}
```

Comment: here's a helpful link: http://codepen.io/WinterJoey/pen/sfFaK

Comment: I want to jnow what that regax is doing ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: or even better https://regex101.com/, just copy paste and read

Comment: could you please tell more I am trying to see

Comment: If you just want to understand this regex, why not just ask that? Why add Angular and filters? Why not tag it with regex instead of angularjs-scope(?!) tag?